# BadZipfile Pandas XLRD error when opening Excel File

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, xlrd

I am currently trying to read an excel file using Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64 bit) on Windows and creating a data frame from its contents.  Here's a snippet from my code:

```
import argparse
import pandas as pd

# xl.py

# Adding an input argument 
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-i","--input",help="Input Excel file to generate df",
                    type=argparse.FileType('r'))
args = parser.parse_args()

# Reading the Excel File
xls = pd.ExcelFile(args.input)
df = xls.parse('Sheet 1')

# printing for debug
print df.head()
```

When running the following:
`python xl.py -i test.xlsx`

I receive a Traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File ".\xl.py", line 11
    File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 194, in __init__
       self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=data)
    File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 399, in open_workbook 
       zf = zipfile.ZipFile(timemachine.BYTES_IO(file_contents))
    File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda\lib\zipfile.py", line 770, in __init__
        self._RealGetContents()
    File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda\zipfile.py", line 711 in _RealGetContents
       raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
zipfile.BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
```

**When I move my xlsx file over to a 64 bit GNU/Linux server running python 2.7.5.  I was able to run this script no problem**.  However, I need it to be function in windows since I will be using pyinstaller to make it executable in the future (i.e. removing positional args and allowing people to double click it).

Any idea why Windows is having a problem with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: **SOLVED**. I need to read the arguemnt in binary mode to get past this problem on windows:

`parser.add_argument("-i","--input",help="Input Excel file to generate df",
                    type=argparse.FileType('r'))
args = parser.parse_args()`

Comment: Don't you mean `FileType('rb')` ?